# How to print an entire PHP array in a single HTML cell?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a HTML table where there are some columns. Each column is showing its own value. But in one cell of the table, I want to display an entire array of item-names separated by commas. I want the table cell to display like this:

| User ID | Item Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1, name2, name3,.... |

`$allitemnames` holds the array values like name1, name2, name3 etc

This is my current code for fetching the array of items:

```
$itemnames="SELECT item_name FROM orderhistory WHERE uid='$userid' AND payment_mode = 'Cash'";
$itemnamescon=$con->query($itemnames);
$allitemnames=array();
while($x = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemnamescon))
{
     $allitemnames[]=array('item_name'=> $x['item_name']);
}
$itemsarrayresult = implode(", ", $allitemnames);
```

It's fetching the array properly because when I try to Echo out the `$allitemnames` outside the HTML table then it prints the whole array. But the main problem arises when i try to print it in a HTML table cell. I used the following code to print it:

```
echo"<tr style='color:white; background-color:#262626'>
<td><center>".$userid."</center></td>
<td><center>".$itemsarrayresult."</center></td>
</tr>";
```

This code does print multiple names in a single cell but the output is not at all what I want. It prints only **"Array, Array, Array...."**

Firstly it shows this warning message many times and it says-

> Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\pendingpayments.php on line 62

and secondly the table looks like this:

| User ID | Item Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Array, Array, Array,.... |

I've had a look online but every forum I've come across has been people trying to loop through and print 1 value per **t**d, not all values in one `td`

Comment: replace $allitemnames[]=array('item_name'=> $x['item_name']); by $allitemnames[]=$x['item_name'];

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? `$allitemnames` does not look like an array of strings to me

Comment: Including `[]` on the end of `$allitemnames` automatically pushes the result of the right-hand expression to the end of the `$allitemnames` array. Why have you elected to wrap the result of the right-hand expression in an `array()`, thus creating a single-item array that is then pushed into a larger `$allitemnames` array? This doesn't seem like what you've intended here.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of different approaches to this:

In php:

```php
while($x = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemnamescon))
{
     $allitemnames[]=$x['item_name'];
}
$itemsarrayresult = implode(", ", $allitemnames);
```

In MySQL:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(item_name) FROM orderhistory WHERE uid='$userid' AND payment_mode = 'Cash'"
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an multidimension array. You don't need her.
Do like this:

```
$allitemnames[] = $x['item_name'];
```

Answer (score -1):

can you change your code as following and retry?

```
$itemsarrayresult = ''; //initialization
while($x = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemnamescon))
{
     $itemsarrayresult .= $x['item_name'].","; //concatenation
}
//now you need to display but variable will have an addirional ',' at the end so we will trim it using rtrim
echo '<tr style="color:white; background-color:#262626">
    <td><center>'.$userid.'</center></td>
    <td><center>'.rtrim($itemsarrayresult,',').'</center></td>
   </tr>';
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it